# OpenCart PHP error in VQCache file

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

We just launched a redesign of a client's ecommerce site running on OpenCart. We're trying to track down an error we're seeing in the Error Logs, but it's been eluding us thus far:

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: route in .../vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_view_theme_margaretha_template_common_header.tpl on line 360

The code on that line is:

```
<?php if ($this->request->get['route'] != 'common/home') { ?>
  <div id="free-shipping">
    <p>Free shipping on all orders!</p>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I'm not sure why this is throwing an error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Change your if condition as follows:

```
<?php if (isset($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route'] != 'common/home') { ?>
    <div id="free-shipping">
        <p>Free shipping on all orders!</p>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

The code may be in your theme folder's `common/header.tpl` or in some vqmod xml file (editing the file `/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_view_theme_margaretha_template_common_header.tpl` won't make any change).

Have a nice day !!